# How do I capture northern lights?

Tags: lens, camera-settings, astrophotography, nikon-d3400

I have a Nikon d3400 with kit lens 18-55 mm af-p DX. What is the right camera settings for northern lights photography?

Answer (score 0):

Use manual settings.
Set the focus on lens to manual and set to to just before infinity.

Set the aperture to wide open.
Start with lowest possible ISO, this can be changed if there is movements in the images later.
Set the exposure time to a few seconds and use two or 10 seconds timer to take the picture to make sure no movements from your hand will shake the camera.

If the northern lights move or if there are clouds or something else showing movement blur then raise the ISO to get a faster shutter speed.

But don't go too far or you may add noise to the image.